# Left Join for Rightsystem

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a:

-"**user**"-table (*id*, *name*, *pass*...)

-"**groups**"-table (*id*, *name*)

-"**user_group**"-table (*id*, *iduser*, *idgroup*)

-"**menu**"-table (*id*, *name*, *groups*)

Every "menu"-point can have "one" groupid in the group-column.
Every user can have zero, one or more idgroup...

```
user-table:
id, name
1, ingo
2, bernd

groups-table:
id, name
1, group1
2, group2
3, group3

user_groups-table
id, userid, groupid
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 3
3, 2, 1
```

so ingo is Member from Group1 und Group3 and Bernd is only Member from Group1

the  menu-table can look like this:
id, name, groups,...
1, Menupoint1, 0 (no group)
2, Menupoint2, 3
3, Menupoint3, 2

There is a register Session with the Userid called $_SESSION["uid"]

So if ingo is logged in he can see the Menupoint1 an Menupoint2. not Menupoint3 cause he is no Member... I think you know waht I mean...

I try this syntax whitout the result i want to have:

```
$uid=$_SESSION[uid];
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * from menu LEFT JOIN user_groups 
ON menu.groups=user_groups.groupid
WHERE user_groups.groupid=? order by name");
$stmt->execute(array($uid));
```

Can you give some hint to the right way..

Sorry for my ugly English - I am from Germany.
But this seems me the best forum for my question :))

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition on the second table from the `where` clause to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT *
from menu m LEFT JOIN
     user_groups ug
     ON m.groups = ug.groupid AND
        ug.groupid = ?
order by name;
```

Your formulation turns the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.  When there is no match in the second table, the value of `groupid` is `NULL`, which fails the comparison.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ;) I Try this code but there is no result i can see from the sql-table...:(